# SFMC Postman error 400 BAD request when requesting Access token for SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

I may be doing some rookie error but can't figure out what am i doing wrong.
Just want to get access token for SFMC below is what I have

```
{
"grant_type":"client_credentials",
"client_id": "XXXXX",
"client_secret": "XXXX",
"account_id":"1234"
```

}

Using below URL for POST

```
https://XXXXX.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/Token
```

getting below error

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "Make sure that the client ID and client secret are valid and that the following parameters are not empty or null: client ID, client secret, and grant type.",
"error_uri": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs"
```

}

I have gone through help documentation available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm) but it didn't helped.

Any suggestions how can I receive access token for SFMC.

Error says about grant type parameter as I was also passing them like the example shown in above URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have replicated your error when I pass the following request

```
{
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "clientid": "{{clientId}}",
    "clientsecret": "{{clientSecret}}",
    "account_id":"{{accountId}}"
}
```

It should be

```
{
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "client_id": "{{clientId}}",
    "client_secret": "{{clientSecret}}",
    "account_id":"{{accountId}}"
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm

Comment: Already tried as you can see line line in my post.

Comment: @pragyanshukukreti Can you provide the payload you are using for V2 route, the payload you provided in the question is for the V1 route

Comment: thanks E, I'v edited my question. I pasted as i tried everything :)

Comment: @pragyanshukukreti review my edited response

Comment: LOL.... as i said i was doing some rookie error but this was not even rookie. It's very silly. thanks for figuring this out.